# Onclick toggle data attribute

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to toggle a data attribute (e.g `data-equalizer-watch`) on click using Jquery?

Here's the html:

```
<a class="accordion-expander" href="#" data-equalizer-watch>
```

So onclick I want it to look like this:

```
<a class="accordion-expander" href="#">
```

I know this is wrong but something along these lines:

```
$(".accordion-expander").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).toggleData('equalizer-watch');
});
```

Comment: Do you want to change the actual HTML attribute, or "just" the inner data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the `data-equalizer-watch` value to `false` with `.data()` method in JQuery to toggle it.

```
 $(this).data("equalizer-watch", false);
```

But if you want to delete it from the display, just do this:

```
$(this).removeAttr("data-equalizer-watch");
```

If you use `.attr()` method to change the value, the `data` is not rendered.You must set `data` attribut with `.data()` method to re-render it.

Answer (score 1):

To make this work you can toggle back and forth between `attr()` and `removeAttr()` method calls depending on whether the element has the attribute when clicked:

```js
$(".accordion-expander").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var method = $(this).is('[data-equalizer-watch]') ? 'removeAttr' : 'attr';
  $(this)[method]('data-equalizer-watch', '');
});
```

```css
a[data-equalizer-watch] {
  color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="accordion-expander" href="#" data-equalizer-watch>
  foo
</a>
```

However it's not guaranteed that this logic would work as you require. It would depend on how the dependant logic accesses the attribute.

A much better solution would be to *always* include the `data` attribute on the element but have it's value as a boolean flag which you toggle, like this:

```js
$(".accordion-expander").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $el = $(this);
  $el.data('equalizer-watch', !$el.data('equalizer-watch'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="accordion-expander" href="#" data-equalizer-watch="true">
  foo
</a>
```

Comment: The second snippet is much better and would work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

`.toggleData()` is not a default jQuery method, **so let's create one**:

Than inside the mini-plugin use jQuery's [removeAttr()](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) and [attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) methods.

```js
$.fn.toggleData = function(dname) {
  var d = `data-${dname}`;
  return this.is(`[${d}]`) ? this.removeAttr(d) : this.attr(d,'');
};


$(".accordion-expander").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).toggleData('equalizer-watch');
});
```

```css
[data-equalizer-watch] { color: fuchsia; }
```

```html
<a class="accordion-expander" href="#" data-equalizer-watch>CLICK ME</a>
<a class="accordion-expander" href="#">CLICK ME</a>


<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```